# Rails4 Select - How to set the default selected item for users of a site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, date, select

I am getting the the Gender during profile creation and storing it in database.
In update profile page, I want the correct Gender of the user to be selected.

I am setting the Gender as follows in my webapp.
I am using boolean type for Gender.
First, I added the new columns in migration file

**db/migrate/[timestamp]_add_admin_to_users.rb**

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, default: false

    #Start - Adding for gender and dob
    add_column :users, :date_of_birth, :datetime
    add_column :users, :is_female, :boolean, default: false
    #End - Adding for gender and dob

  end
end
```

Ran the following to create tables with my new columns

```
$bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Decided to create Select boxes because I couldn't create radio buttons after repeated attempts

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.
GENDER_TYPES = [ ["Male","0"], [ "Female","1" ] ]
validates_inclusion_of :is_female, in: [true, false]
.
.
```

This is Select box snippet from view of my Sign up form

**app/views/users/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :is_female, "Gender" %>
<%= f.select :is_female, User::GENDER_TYPES, class: 'form-control' %>
```

I have the same Select box snippet Update Profile form

**app/views/users/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :is_female, "Gender" %>
<%= f.select :is_female, User::GENDER_TYPES, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Everytime Gender is Male.
Can anyone please share how to set the gender which the user gave while signing up?

For instance,
When a female user signs up, I want female to be selected when they select update profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is because you are setting giving the options for gender types as 0 and 1 while you are using boolean - true/false to represent `is_female`. Try this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  GENDER_TYPES = [['Male', true], ['Female', false]]
...
```

This should work as now we are strictly working with boolean values - not 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done by `selected` html attribute like below

```
 <%= f.select :is_female, User::GENDER_TYPES, class: 'form-control', :selected => "male" %>
```

Comment: thanks but wont it set male as selected for female users too?

Comment: yes, but you can pass whatever you like in place of "male". It was just an example.

Comment: Yeah @maximus This is also working but I dont know how. Thank you very much. Aren't we explicitly saying to select male? How does this work? If you can kindly point me to resources to read, I will be grateful. I want to learn.